# Safari Takes Excessive Time to Load and Render Server-Sent Events (SSE) in Django Application

Tags: reactjs, django, safari, frontend, server-sent-events

Here's a brief overview of our implementation:
**Backend (Django)**: Sends SSEs using django-eventstream. Events are sent to a URL like [https://devbackend.marshallgoldsmith.ai/events/{session_id}](https://devbackend.marshallgoldsmith.ai/events/%7Bsession_id%7D), where {session_id} is a unique identifier.

**Frontend**: Uses fetchEventSource to listen to the events from the above URL. We handle various event scenarios such as onmessage, onerror, and onclose. The event stream opens fine in Chrome and even displays correctly when the URL is opened directly in a Chrome browser tab.
Issue with Safari:

When accessing the event stream URL in Safari, it keeps loading indefinitely and does not display any events, unlike in Chrome.
There are no apparent error messages in the Safari console.

we checked cross-origin issues and other compatibility issues and searched. But no luck.

So if anyone face this kind of issue, please let us know. that will be more helpful.

Thanks